# How to delete an item from JSON array in SQL Server

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, t-sql

How can I delete an item from JSON array in SQL Server.

Here is my JSON :

```json
[
  {
    "nodeId": 15,
    "nodeCondition": "needRepairing=true"
  },
  {
    "nodeId": 16,
    "nodeCondition": "needWashing=false"
  }
]
```

which is stored in a column. I want to delete elements by their **`nodeId`**.

Comment: Why are you storing JSON in SQL Server in the first place? Why isn't your database normalized?

Comment: **Exactly** what version of SQL Server are you using? Different versions of SQL Server have different JSON-processing capabilities....

Comment: Do you have any requirements w.r.t. transactional safety?

Comment: Does the stored JSON always have only `nodeId` and `nodeCondition` kay\value pairs?

Comment: I use SQL Server 2016.

Comment: @Zhorov yes. only nodeId and nodeCondition

Comment: @MustafaBazghandi, I don't think you can delete an item from JSON array, so you need to parse, filter and rebuild the JSON array again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you can delete an item from JSON array, so you need to parse, filter and rebuild the JSON array again.

Table:

```
SELECT *
INTO JsonTable
FROM (VALUES
   (N'[
      {"nodeId":13,"nodeCondition":"needRepairing=true"},
      {"nodeId":14,"nodeCondition":"needRepairing=true"},
      {"nodeId":15,"nodeCondition":"needRepairing=true"},
      {"nodeId":16,"nodeCondition":"needWashing=false"}
      ]')
) v (JsonColumn)
```

Statement:

```
UPDATE JsonTable
SET JsonColumn = (
   SELECT nodeId, nodeCondition
   FROM OPENJSON(JsonColumn) WITH (
      nodeId int '$.nodeId', 
      nodeCondition nvarchar(1000) '$.nodeCondition'
   )
   WHERE nodeId NOT IN (13, 15)
   FOR JSON PATH
)
```

Result:

| JsonColumn |
| --- |
| [{"nodeId":14,"nodeCondition":"needRepairing=true"},{"nodeId":16,"nodeCondition":"needWashing=false"}] |

Note, that in case of JSON object, you can delete a specific key with `JSON_MODIFY()`, using `lax` mode and `NULL` as new value.

Answer (score 1):

for example , if you want to remove nodeId 16 then you could try this :

```
DECLARE @YourJson NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'[
{"nodeId":15,"nodeCondition":"needRepairing=true"},
{"nodeId":16,"nodeCondition":"needWashing=false"}
]';
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM OPENJSON(@YourJson) WITH(nodeId 
INT,nodeCondition NVARCHAR(MAX)) WHERE nodeId <> 16) AS R FOR JSON 
AUTO;
GO
```